# In a SmartPy smart contract, is there 'continue' or 'break' for loop?

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy

In a SmartPy smart contract, is there 'continue' or 'break' for loop?

When I use 'continue' for loop, an error occurred. 'Error: invalid syntax'

Comment: Could you share the contract?

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: I'm using smartpy

Answer (score 1):

There is no `sp.continue` or `sp.break` inside a `sp.for` at the moment.
We may add that in the future.

Please keep in mind that iterating on non trivially small lists is usually a bad idea inside a smart contract.